How to improve multilingual speech recognition for programming terms?
I’m developing an AI-powered multilingual simultaneous translator to understand programming lectures in different languages. The main issue is accurate speech recognition because programming often includes many English terms and abbreviations, which existing solutions struggle with.
I’ve tested these APIs: Whisper by OpenAI, Google STT, and Azure STT, and here are the results:

Whisper works well for multilingual tasks but struggles with short audio clips. It sometimes adds irrelevant phrases or inappropriate words.
Azure STT is excellent for streaming but skips words in short audio clips during regular requests. It also doesn’t support multilinguality in one model, so it struggles with terms in other languages.
Google STT provides timestamps and word confidence scores. I tried two approaches:

Running two streams for different languages and comparing word probabilities based on timestamps (but timestamps often differ by up to 1 second).
Splitting audio into small parts and rechecking low-confidence words using an English model. However, this resulted in too many
unnecessary English words.



I’m considering fine-tuning a pre-trained model like Azure STT to handle programming-specific terms better.
Question:
What are the best methods to improve simultaneous speech recognition for multilingual programming-related terms? Is fine-tuning the only option, or are there other approaches I should try?

Firstly, run azure STT for the primary language and Whisper for programming terms, then merge both the results.

Splitting audio into overlapping 5-second segments to improve short clip accuracy.

Code:
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import whisper

def azure_stt(audio_file):
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="YourKey", region="YourRegion")
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=audio_file)
    recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    result = recognizer.recognize_once()
    return result.text

def whisper_stt(audio_file):
    model = whisper.load_model("medium")
    result = model.transcribe(audio_file)
    return result['text']

def merge_transcripts(azure_text, whisper_text):
    return f"{azure_text} (Programming terms: {whisper_text})"

# Example Usage
audio_path = "lecture_clip.wav"
azure_result = azure_stt(audio_path)
whisper_result = whisper_stt(audio_path)
final_result = merge_transcripts(azure_result, whisper_result)

print(final_result)

Added key programming terms like “API,” “JSON,” or “Python” to Azure STT’s phrase list. Reprocessing low-confidence parts with Whisper or Google STT (English model).
Result:


Thank you for the advice! Right now, my system has an average delay of about 8 seconds. Analyzing overlapping 5-second chunks could slow it down a lot, maybe even twice as much, and it wouldn’t feel like real-time translation anymore. As for dictionaries, they could cause mistakes with other words, so I decided not to use them. But I really appreciate your idea, thanks!

@Inozem Good to accept the solution if it has solved the problem. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO Link
